# How do I hook invoking controller action in MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis

In my MVC3 application I have lots of controllers and actions. Sometimes an exception is raised while executing an action. I want to be able to log that and let the exception be handled by MVC.

Something like this pseudocode:

```
try {
    MvcInvokeControllerAction( controller, action, params );
} catch( Exception e ) {
    trace( "Error while invoking " + controller + "-" +
       action + " with " + params + " details: " + getDetails( e ) );
    throw;
}
```

What I want is to be able to catch the exception before it is first processed by MVC because sometimes MVC kicking in raises another exception and I see the latter in `Application_Error()` and the original exception is lots.

How do I achieve such hooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override [**OnException** Method](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onexception.aspx&ei=UnoyT4PpFMqE8gOH65HnDQ&usg=AFQjCNEZXSt029sb6AlaTt7xwqiqqvExhw&sig2=aZwzUQFmloMBOFmTEHSaug) On your **Basecontrollor**.

This will be a Catch block for all exceptions in Controllor Actions. just Exetnd all your Controllors from Basecontrollor

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
}
```

Example

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{

    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnException(filterContext);
        // Handle error here
    }
}


public class TestController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // If any exceptions then will be caught by 
        // BaseController OnException method
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I let the exception propagate? Do I just call the base `OnException()`?

Comment: See example.  no need to call OnException. MVc will automatically call OnException for any errors in Controllor Actions